# convert GMT to PST in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, timezone

How can I convert a string:

```
Mon, 28 Jul 2014 09:33:44 GMT
```

to PST? using angular JS (preferable) or rather javascript.

I went through other thread but didn't find any to the point/complete/crisp solution.
People say we should not handle date/time zone myself, so is it mandatory to use some existing lib? if so suggest some good lib and its implementation.

Comment: Asking for lib or tool recommendation is not exactly in the scope of stackoverflow, but please take a look at Moment.js

Comment: I have asked for any feasible and correct workaround if there exists.

Comment: Thats why I didn't flag your question and instead commented ;)
Anyway, here's a link if you haven't found it yet: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)